# Need landing page to redirect if record doesn't exist in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
SET @emailaddress = QueryParameter("email") /* gets the encrypted string */)
SET @thanks = QueryParameter("thanks")

set @Contact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","Id,FirstName,MobilePhone,LastName,Preferred_Business_Email_Address__c,Fund_Overview_Webcasts__c,BDC_FA__c,Global_REIT_II_Communication__c,Fund_Updates_or_News__c,Marketing_Materials__c,Individual_Communications__c,SMS_Message_Opt_In__c,Preferred_First_Name__c,Preferred_Last_Name__c,ISC_Name__c,ISC_Email__c,ISC_Phone__c,ISC_Title__c,Contact_Owner_Name__c,Contact_Owner_Email__c,Contact_Owner_Phone__c,Contact_Owner_Title__c,Preferred_Broker_Dealer_Name__c,Broker_Dealer_Name__c,Email,HasOptedOutOfEmail","Email", "=", v(@emailaddress)) 
Set @ContactRow = ROW(@Contact,1)
```

I am building a landing page in MC that will display a persons information based on the information they have in SF, they will be able to submit a form and update their preference (its a preference center).

I am using the url to populate their email address and use that to query back to SF for the right contact. (example: testsite.com/Main?email=testemail@gmail.com)

My problem is if a user somehow gets to this page through other means or they don't have a record in SF but they do in MC they will either get a really ugly error message or the LP will go and find the first contact in SF and display that..

So I need a way for my code to tell me they aren't in there then redirect them.

```
set @rowCount = rowcount(@ContactRow)

IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
```

I've seen something like this done before but i've only got it to work with a row pull from a Data Extension.

Has anyone solved this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [Redirect](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/#Redirect) `AmpScript` function to redirect subscribers if record doesn't exist in Salesforce and below is sample code.

```
%%[
SET @emailaddress = QueryParameter("email") /* gets the encrypted string */)
SET @thanks = QueryParameter("thanks")

SET @Contact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","Id,FirstName,MobilePhone,LastName,Preferred_Business_Email_Address__c,Fund_Overview_Webcasts__c,BDC_FA__c,Global_REIT_II_Communication__c,Fund_Updates_or_News__c,Marketing_Materials__c,Individual_Communications__c,SMS_Message_Opt_In__c,Preferred_First_Name__c,Preferred_Last_Name__c,ISC_Name__c,ISC_Email__c,ISC_Phone__c,ISC_Title__c,Contact_Owner_Name__c,Contact_Owner_Email__c,Contact_Owner_Phone__c,Contact_Owner_Title__c,Preferred_Broker_Dealer_Name__c,Broker_Dealer_Name__c,Email,HasOptedOutOfEmail","Email", "=", v(@emailaddress)) 

IF RowCount(@Contact) > 0 Then
    SET @FirstName = Field(Row(@Contact,1),"FirstName")
    SET @LastName = Field(Row(@Contact,1),"LastName")
Else
    Redirect("Error Page URL")
EndIf
]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the **RetrieveSalesforceObjects()** function, I would recommend checking the value of @emailaddress.  I suspect your code is returning the 1st contact record when this variable is blank.  Consider using the [Empty()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Empty) function.  You could also verify the format of the @emailaddress variable using the [isEmailAddress()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#IsEmailAddress) function.

```
%%[
SET @emailaddress = QueryParameter("email") /* gets the encrypted string */)
SET @thanks = QueryParameter("thanks")

if Empty(@emailaddress) then
    Redirect("Error Page URL")
else
    SET @Contact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","Id,FirstName,MobilePhone,LastName,Preferred_Business_Email_Address__c,Fund_Overview_Webcasts__c,BDC_FA__c,Global_REIT_II_Communication__c,Fund_Updates_or_News__c,Marketing_Materials__c,Individual_Communications__c,SMS_Message_Opt_In__c,Preferred_First_Name__c,Preferred_Last_Name__c,ISC_Name__c,ISC_Email__c,ISC_Phone__c,ISC_Title__c,Contact_Owner_Name__c,Contact_Owner_Email__c,Contact_Owner_Phone__c,Contact_Owner_Title__c,Preferred_Broker_Dealer_Name__c,Broker_Dealer_Name__c,Email,HasOptedOutOfEmail","Email", "=", v(@emailaddress)) 

    IF RowCount(@Contact) > 0 Then
        SET @FirstName = Field(Row(@Contact,1),"FirstName")
        SET @LastName = Field(Row(@Contact,1),"LastName")
    Else
        Redirect("Error Page URL")
    EndIf
EndIf
]%%
```